# Solving radical and polynomial expressions

Tags: polynomials, radicals

$2x^3 +3x^2 +2x+1 = x(2x+3)(\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{x}} )$

Only solution i could find is x = -1, the LHS can be expressed as $(x+1)(2x^2+x+1)$
and the LHS has a $\sqrt{\frac{x^3+1}{x}}$ which has a factor of $\sqrt {(x+1)}$
.

I know that this is not the only solution, what are the others? I always have a hard time solving these kinds of problems especially if they become systems, what tips/tricks can you utilize in solving problems like this one?

Comment: You do not need tricks. Squaring is the first step, and this you could have done yourself. After that, one has an polynomial equation, where one can usually factorize the polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

If you square both sides you get 
$$
8x^4+12x^3-2x^2-5x+1 = 0
$$
If you search for rational solutions, you will find $x=-1$ and $x=\frac 12$, and so the equation will be equivalent to
$$
(x+1)(2x-1)(4x^2+4x-1)=0
$$
So we get to real solutions, $x=-1,\frac 12$, and a pair of complex solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Squaring the whole equation and factorizing we get
$$\left( 2\,x-1 \right)  \left( x+1 \right)  \left( 4\,{x}^{2}+4\,x-1
 \right) 
=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Squaring both sides and substracting yields
$$
0=8x^4 + 12x^3 - 2x^2 - 5x + 1=(4x^2 + 4x - 1)(2x - 1)(x + 1)
$$
and this can be easily solved.